# User interface objects in xib file not changing size in interface builder or code ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, frame, xib

I have three labels in a xib file and I wanted to change their sizes. So in interface builder I made the necessary changes, but when I run the app the sizes of the labels did not change. So I tried to change the frame sizes via code by calling the CGRectMake method. But when I run the app the sizes still do not change.

Auto layout and size classes are off. Don't know what the problem is. Just for info I am upgrading a very old app that uses ios 2, so maybe that has something to do with it? Also the 3 labels are sub viewed with another label, but I do not know why that would cause a problem.

Comment: The app was written in ios 2. I have to upgrade it to ios 8+

Comment: It's ok,sorry, I can't help you!